# Application changing its name according to Android

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I developed an app using Android Studio called eCoding.  However, on some devices with the old Android, the name is ok.  on current Android devices, the name changes to FolioReader (framework I used).  does anyone know why this happens and how to fix it?

[My androidmanifest and strings](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ixOEWABUC3KtTdYLn1_HWzVZBayz_iWD/view)

Comment: Provide your manifest file.

Comment: @Yegorf I add in post

Answer (score 2):

I think you are using `FolioReader` library and the name is taken from its res  so in your manifest file you need to use your own name like below

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.yourpackage"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
```

then

```
<application
tools:replace="label" 
 android:label="YourAppName"
../>
```

### Update :

use label with another string name from

```
 android:label="@string/app_name"
```

to

```
android:label="@string/app_name_txt"`
```

and try if the above Solution not working

Comment: Look my androidmanifest and strings (link on post)

Comment: use label with another string name from ` android:label="@string/app_name"` to ` android:label="@string/app_name_txt"` and try I hope this help

Comment: You are Welcome, please upvote the answer